# How to get the id from all 3 identical checkboxes in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to learn jQuery and I want all three identical select boxes to update a variable id when selected.

I can get the first select box to show the id in an alert but can't figure out how to get the other two select boxes to work.

I'm doing something wrong with the .each because it's not targeting every select box with the id of #mySelect.

I want all three select boxes to work exactly the same as the first select box.

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/BxKvB/113/

```
<select name="mySelect" id="selectID">
 <option id="myid1" value="somevalue1">somevalue</option>
 <option id="myid2" value="somevalue2">somevalue</option>
 <option id="myid3" value="somevalue3">somevalue</option>
</select>

<select name="mySelect" id="selectID">
 <option id="myid1" value="somevalue1">somevalue</option>
 <option id="myid2" value="somevalue2">somevalue</option>
 <option id="myid3" value="somevalue3">somevalue</option>
</select>

<select name="mySelect" id="selectID">
 <option id="myid1" value="somevalue1">somevalue</option>
 <option id="myid2" value="somevalue2">somevalue</option>
 <option id="myid3" value="somevalue3">somevalue</option>
</select>

<script>
    $('#selectID').each(function() {
        $(this).change(function() {
        var optionID = $('option:selected').attr('id');
        alert(optionID);
        });
   });

  </script>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Plus I don't see a single checkbox in the code you posted.

Comment: Yeah, I see that I wrote checkbox instead of select box. My bad.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. For example use the same class for all check boxes, try this :

```
<select class="something" name="mySelect" id="selectID">
 <option id="myid1" value="somevalue1">somevalue</option>
 <option id="myid2" value="somevalue2">somevalue</option>
 <option id="myid3" value="somevalue3">somevalue</option>
</select>

<select class="something" name="mySelect" id="selectID">
 <option id="myid1" value="somevalue1">somevalue</option>
 <option id="myid2" value="somevalue2">somevalue</option>
 <option id="myid3" value="somevalue3">somevalue</option>
</select>
```

In jquery :

```
    $(".something").change(function() {
        var optionID = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
        alert(optionID);
    });
```

Comment: You can always [edit] your answer than deleting one and adding another.

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

```
$('#selectID').find('option').change(function(){
 alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Keep in mind that #selectID needs to be unique.

Also more generic thing for every select:

```
$('select').find('option').change(function(){
     alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$('select[name="mySelect"]').each(function() {
  $(this).change(function() {
   var optionID = $('option:selected').attr('id');
    alert($(this).attr("class") + optionID);
  });
});

<select name="mySelect" id="selectID" class="1">
 <option id="myid1" value="somevalue1">somevalue</option>
 <option id="myid2" value="somevalue2">somevalue</option>
 <option id="myid3" value="somevalue3">somevalue</option>
</select>

<select name="mySelect" id="selectID" class="2">
 <option id="myid1" value="somevalue1">somevalue</option>
 <option id="myid2" value="somevalue2">somevalue</option>
 <option id="myid3" value="somevalue3">somevalue</option>
</select>

<select name="mySelect" id="selectID" class="3">
 <option id="myid1" value="somevalue1">somevalue</option>
 <option id="myid2" value="somevalue2">somevalue</option>
 <option id="myid3" value="somevalue3">somevalue</option>
</select>
<span id="result"></span>
```